# Cannot connect to certain sites after moving computer

Tags: networking, internet, connection

I recently moved my computer to a new location in town. We have the same ISP, Eastlink, but new cable modem, and new switch. I am connecting via Ethernet, but the effect is the same on Wi-Fi. I have Google DNS specified in my iMac's network settings.

I cannot connect to certain sites, e.g. my App Engine sites such as [pickthis.io](http://www.pickthis.io/) and [modelr.io](http://www.modelr.io/), blogspot blogs, and also [wikipedia.org](http://en.wikipedia.org). They all give me this in Chrome:

> No data received
>
> ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
>
> Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.

Or this in Firefox:

> The connection was reset

According to [isup.me](http://isup.me/pickthis.io) and [uptimerobot.com](http://uptimerobot.com/) my sites are up. There are no server errors on my servers. And I can ping them:

```
PING pickthis.io (216.239.32.21): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 216.239.32.21: icmp_seq=0 ttl=47 time=79.611 ms
```

I can `traceroute` (see below). The only thing that looks odd there is the long time it seems to take just to talk to my modem, but I don't really know what I'm looking at:

```
traceroute: Warning: pickthis.io has multiple addresses; using 216.239.38.21
traceroute to pickthis.io (216.239.38.21), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1)  2.028 ms  5.833 ms  9.605 ms
 2  * * *
 3  nf-step-arris1.eastlink.ca (24.222.XXX.XXX)  20.068 ms  29.658 ms  30.532 ms
 4  ns-hlfx-dr002.ns.eastlink.ca (24.215.102.145)  29.538 ms  19.712 ms  29.761 ms
 5  ns-hlfx-br002.ns.eastlink.ca (24.215.102.221)  37.077 ms  29.857 ms  69.800 ms
 6  ns-hlfx-br001.ns.eastlink.ca (24.215.102.9)  30.691 ms  29.781 ms  15.008 ms
 7  google.eastlink.ca (24.215.101.10)  49.422 ms  49.498 ms  59.932 ms
 8  209.85.255.232 (209.85.255.232)  50.251 ms  45.036 ms  47.300 ms
 9  72.14.235.34 (72.14.235.34)  80.015 ms
    216.239.46.160 (216.239.46.160)  69.673 ms  77.874 ms
10  209.85.243.142 (209.85.243.142)  76.027 ms
    216.239.40.28 (216.239.40.28)  71.201 ms
    209.85.243.144 (209.85.243.144)  70.454 ms
11  216.239.40.252 (216.239.40.252)  80.441 ms
    216.239.41.58 (216.239.41.58)  77.914 ms  64.498 ms
12  * * *
13  any-in-2615.1e100.net (216.239.38.21)  73.243 ms  86.366 ms  71.145 ms
```

I'm aware of [this similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/50523/cannot-connect-to-certain-websites), but I've had this problem for over 2 weeks. I have run out of things to search or try. Any help or insight appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Still no idea what caused this, but in the end we moved to a different ISP and the problem went away instantly with no other changes to anything. (FWIW, we switched to fibre optic service from a cable service, but I assume that's irrelevant.)